# Nautilus doesn't launch on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

When I type `nautilus` I have these lines:

```
(nautilus:28316): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed    
(nautilus:28316): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Impossible d'enregistrer l'application: Le délai d'attente est dépassé   
(nautilus:28316): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
    (nautilus:28316): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance    
(nautilus:28316): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I tried to reinstall Nautilus, but that did not fix the problem. Does somebody have any ideas as to how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
ps awx | grep nautilus
```

find the process using nautilus

in my case it was

```
1869 ?        Sl     0:01 nautilus -n
```

then kill process

```
sudo kill -TERM 1869
```

do not forget to use the same number